Track data by dropdown list
I run a restaurant and have created sheets to track server and bartender sales/tipshare etc.
I cannot just keep all employees on the same row. As sometimes an employee will be a server, bartender, or event server. All of these positions have different tip share.
I created a dropdown list of all of my employees. Is there a way that I can link their name so that I can create a summary sheet of all employees data, for whatever position they worked for the day?
So far, all of the information I am finding is about creating a dropdown list.

Welcome to StackOverFlow!  Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Make sure to add input and expected output as a plain text table to the question. Click here to create a markdown table, which is easier to copy/paste as well.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Is there a way that I can link their name so that I can create a summary sheet of all employees data, for whatever position they worked for the day? How about an adjacent dropdown list of positions for the day; then you can select the employee and their position by day.
